# Laravel export to excel and save file to folder

Tags: php, excel, laravel, export, maatwebsite-excel

i want to export data to excel and save it to folder_project/storage/excel/exports

but the file is not save into the folder.

i use laravel and maatwebsite-excel. please help me

```html
$file = Excel::create('Export Data',function($excel) use($user){
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1',function($sheet) use($user){
        $sheet->fromArray($user);
    });
})->save('xlsx', storage_path('excel/exports'), true);
```

Comment: Is this Maatwebsite-excel 2.1 and Is your storage folder writable?

Comment: yes, i try this too, but the file still not save})->store('xlsx', storage_path().'\excel\exports', 0777, true, true);

Comment: have you got solution ?

Comment: try using store instead of save

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Excel::create($sheetname, function($excel) use ($user) {
// Set the spreadsheet title, creator, and description
$excel->setTitle('Payments');
$excel->setCreator('Laravel')->setCompany('WJ Gilmore, LLC');
$excel->setDescription('payments file');

// Build the spreadsheet, passing in the payments array
$excel->sheet('sheet1', function($sheet) use ($user) {
$sheet->fromArray($user, null, 'A1', false, false);
});
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: thanks shikha, its works, but it still force user to download, what i want is excel will auto saving to server folder